# Не могли бы вы привести пример реализации наискорейшего спуска?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, оптимизация, машинное-обучение

Есть задача минимизировать функцию двух переменных методом наискорейшего спуска. Я реализовал обычный градиентный спуск с постоянным шагом, но не могу сделать так, чтобы шаг как-то рассчитывался на каждой итерации. Не могли бы вы привести пример работы этого алгоритма (можно только код расчета шага)

Comment: Метод наискорейшего спуска **НЕ** предполагает перерасчёта шага на каждой итерации. Наоборот, вычислив направление и шаг, мы движемся в этом направлении с этим шагом, пока на очередном шаге не получим возрастание целевой функции. Только в этом случае мы считаем новые направление и шаг. Экономия - только за счёт того, что перерасчёт выполняется не на каждом шаге.

Comment: Если всё же хочется динамический шаг - то при движении в направлении рассчитанного ранее градиента применяем обычную одномерную оптимизацию. Но это вменяемо работает только для гладких функций.

Comment: Не хотите воспользоваться [готовыми решениями](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)? Или у вас задача чисто академическая?

Comment: Что, если уменьшать шаг (на сколько конкретно - уже вам решать, хоть в 2 раза, хоть на 1 %) в случае, если очередное значение функции становится "хуже" (больше) предыдущего. Визуально это будет похоже, как мне кажется, на инерцию, когда шарик (текущая точка) по действием гравитации скатывается на дно, с затухающими колебаниями.